# Apply dot and decimals to integer in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an **integer** like `12345`. I want to apply a simple filter in AngularJS in order to get two decimal places:

```
123.45
```

**Update:** Thanks to @benohead for the solution:

```
{{val/100 | number:2}}
```

Comment: check this out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: Yes I am. I need it for a payment processor. The processor interprets the last two digits as cents. And the integer should be displayed more nicely in the frontend so that you know 100 is 1€ and not 100€

Comment: @gauravbhavsar you didn't hear of [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) values?

Comment: @Aameer I already found that page but I am not sure how to implement the solution. Everything I find just moves the comma or dot to the "right", not to the "left"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is divide 12345 by 100 and then use the number filter to display 2 digits after the comma e.g.:

```
{{val/100 | number:2}}
```

Comment: As easy as it is ... Thank you @benohead. That's what I have been looking for!